# Unable to get the good height of the boxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a Website and I came up into this :

I'm using jQuery to get the height of aside content to resize the article content at the equal height.

But strangely i've got issues where the height is not corresponding (by a few pixel) and i cant figure out where this is coming from.

You can see there what i'm fighting with : [maelmayon.fr/teddy.php](http://maelmayon.fr/teddy.php). It is at the bottom of the page.

Here is my **jQuery** (i'm pretty sure its ugly, sorry for that :/ ) :

```
                $(window).load(function(){
                    resizefunction();
                });
                $(function(){
                resizefunction();
                $( window).on('resize',resizefunction);
                });

                 function resizefunction() {
                   var aside1 = $('aside').height();
                   var aside2 = $('.archives').height(); 
                   var content = $('article').height();
                   var total = (aside1 + aside2);
                   $('article').css("height", total+'px');
                }
```

Maybe is it coming from the css..?

If you guys have any clues for me, i'll be truly glad.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the `box-sizing: border-box;` CSS property ?

Comment: What is with so many `resizefunction()` calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from first glance it looks like you should be using `.outerHeight()` instead of `.height()`. outerHeight will look at the border, padding, and margin (if you pass `true` into the function) and it appears that you are using borders on your `aside` elements.

`.height()` **will not** add the padding, border, or margin.

Source: https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Comment: Perfectly working, thank you.
But i've still got a lot of little bug; all along the resize. Do you think jQuery is not adapted to this kind of situation ?

Comment: I would try to rely on CSS the most and only use jQuery/JavaScript as a last resort. jQuery will definitely be able to solve your issues, but this is a post rendering technique, which is primary frowned upon.